# Toggle between plot and table using the same actionButton in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have the `shiny` app below and I would like to toggle between a plot (default) and its table using the same `actionButton()`.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      
      
      actionButton("exc",
                   "Exchange")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput(outputId = "car_plot")
      
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  showPlot <- reactiveVal(TRUE)

 
  
  observeEvent(input$exc, {
    showPlot(!showPlot())
  })
  
  output$car_plot <- renderUI({
    if (showPlot()){
      renderPlot({
        plot(mtcars)
      })
    }
    else{
      renderDataTable(
        datatable(
        mtcars)
      )
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you have is close. I would create separate outputs for the plot and table as below (`output$plot` and `output$table`) and call them depending on state of your `reactiveVal`. Let me know if this is the behavior you had in mind.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  showPlot <- reactiveVal(TRUE)
  
  observeEvent(input$exc, {
    showPlot(!showPlot())
  })
  
  output$car_plot <- renderUI({
    if (showPlot()){
      plotOutput("plot")
    }
    else{
      dataTableOutput("table")
    }
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(mtcars)
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable(datatable(mtcars))
  
}
```